# Inconsistent winbind info on Samba 4 AD domain controller

Tags: linux, samba, domain-controller, winbind

I've setup a Samba 4 AD domain controller on Debian Jessie (samba 4.2.10). Everything's working fine, except that winbind gives wrong user/group information.

I have a sample user "testuser" and a security group "people". Their UNIX attributes are setup as follows:

[image: testuser UNIX attributes] 
[image: people group UNIX attributes]

Yet winbind shows this:

```
root@agnus:~# wbinfo -i testuser
testuser:*:10010:100:Test User:/home/HOME/testuser:/bin/false
```

The UID matches, but everything else is wrong.

My smb.conf contains this:

```
# Global parameters
[global]
        workgroup = HOME
        realm = HOME.LOCAL
        netbios name = AGNUS
        server role = active directory domain controller
        server services = s3fs, rpc, nbt, wrepl, ldap, cldap, kdc, drepl, winbindd, ntp_signd, kcc, dnsupdate
        idmap_ldb:use rfc2307 = yes

        idmap config *:backend = tdb
        idmap config *:range = 2000-9999

        idmap config HOME:backend = ad
        idmap config HOME:schema_mode = rfc2307
        idmap config HOME:range = 10000-99999

        winbind nss info = rfc2307
        winbind enum users = yes
        winbind enum groups = yes
        winbind normalize names = yes
        winbind use default domain = yes
        winbind refresh tickets = yes

[netlogon]
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol/home.local/scripts
        read only = No

[sysvol]
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol
        read only = No
```

What's wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 0):

Basicly nothing. 
Your missing the Template lines since your using samba 4 AD DC. 
Samba 4.2 and 4.3 have different behaivor with getent passwd or wbinfo -u or id.

If possible update to 4.4.3 , google for the debs in the samba list. 
They work good. 
samba 4.4.3 needs winbind to be installed also, ADDC and member, but ! 
all outputs now can be these same.

and about  the template lines.

```
       template homedir (G)

       When filling out the user information for a Windows NT user, the winbindd(8) daemon uses this parameter to fill in the home directory for that user. If the string %D is present it is
       substituted with the user's Windows NT domain name. If the string %U is present it is substituted with the user's Windows NT user name.

       Default: template homedir = /home/%D/%U

       template shell (G)

       When filling out the user information for a Windows NT user, the winbindd(8) daemon uses this parameter to fill in the login shell for that user.

       Default: template shell = /bin/false
```

add these to your DC smb.conf.

Last thing, do read : 
https://www.brightbox.com/blog/2014/03/04/add-cacert-ubuntu-debian/ 
setup like this really makes it more easy.
more questions, ask the samba list.

Comment: and i noticed..  realm = HOME.LOCAL 
.local .lan are reserved TLD's for Apple's mDNS protocol ( zeroconf )
and last, dont add users in the members on the Unix tab, its not needed.